# Parse a javascript generated HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing

I am currently implementing a chrome extension to parse certain websites. I came across a site whose contents are generated by inline/external js code (I Think!). How can I parse a website of this kind. I am trying to extract the whole page through `XMLHttpRequest()` inside my parser. I tried using `eval()` and `html()` of Jquery. With Jquery I could parse some of the elements, but inaccurate.

sample code of my parser:

```
var siteaddress="www.xyz.com/search?q=abcd";
var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
                req.open('GET',siteaddress,true)
                parseHT(req,x);
                req.send(null);


                function parseHT(req_new,x){
                    req_new.onload=function(){
                        //console.log(this.responseText);
                        var jshtml=req_new.responseText;
                        var el = $( '<div></div>' );
                        html=el.html(jshtml)
                        //process steps follows this
```

Thanks

Comment: What you are trying to do will be incredibly difficult. You only get back the plain HTML response in the request as a string. If you want to know what the page looks like after the JS engine has handled al the attached events and amended the DOM, then you need to run one yourself on the HTML. To do that you will also need to download all the CSS and JS files for the given site as well.

Comment: If it doesn't have to be a Chrome extension, try to familiarize yourself with phantomjs. Gives you a lot of options, allows you to grab the site as is or wait for its generation.

Comment: I need it in the form of chrome extension.